# Validate a PNG file

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

Write a program that can validate a PNG file. Your program should follow the [PNG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) and must validate the PNG signature and the 4 critical chunks: `IHDR`, `IDAT`, `PLTE` and `IEND`. Your program must not validate the contents of ancillary chunks, except for their CRC checksums.

Your program must validate the presence of the `PLTE` chunk (that is, `This chunk shall appear for colour type 3, and may appear for colour types 2 and 6; it shall not appear for colour types 0 and 4. There shall not be more than one PLTE chunk.` [ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11PLTE))

Your program must validate chunk order.

Your program must validate CRC checksums.

Your program must validate the compressed data.

You may use runtime code generation+execution (e.g. compress the program itself, or algorithmically write the program itself a la kolmogorov complexity). If any binary blobs are used, their source code will be considered when calculating size.

External library source code size counts towards program size. This is to discourage image-parsing external libraries while allowing e.g. a CRC32 library. Libraries defined in the language specification (aka "standard libraries") don't count as external.

No regex.

You must specify how to input the file. Your program must output to stdout "true" or "false" to answer the question "is the file a valid PNG?".

Failing test files:

```
This file is false.
```

(Yes, that's a plaintext file. Newline-terminated.)

Passing test files:

[image]

Comment: It looks like Mathematica (surprise!) has a built-in to import an image, so you could just wrap some error handling to get a solution. Unfortunately, I don't know Mathematica and I'm not able to run code without paying.

Comment: The ban on binary blobs seems to be imprecise. If their distinguishing feature is not being in ASCII, people will just use base64 or the like to make them not-binary. If their distinguishing feature is being unreadable, doesn't that apply to most golfing submissions?

Comment: @ais523 Even tho code golf tends to be unreadable, a human can parse most of them without having to use an external tool such as a decompiler.

Comment: @Challenger5 Good thing you can't use it! `Your program must not validate the contents of ancillary chunks, except for their CRC checksums.`

Comment: I don't get the "external library" thing. What makes a library external compared to internal?

Comment: @nimi Is it part of the stdlib? If so, it's not external. Is it something you need to download/install yourself? If so, then it's external.

Comment: @nimi If you install *just* the "haskell" package and any *required* deps, what does it come with? What does the standard distribution when you get it off the official website come with?

Comment: @nimi Also you'd need to find a PNG library that doesn't validate any ancillary chunks.

Comment: @nimi Perhaps "Haskell Platform" from https://www.haskell.org/downloads ? I assume that's the official website, and thus "Haskell Platform" is the official standard haskell distribution. (We should probably take this to meta...)

Comment: @SoniEx2 One can tell libpng to not validate ancillary chunks (except for the checksum validations) with `png_set_keep_unknown_chunks(png_ptr,PNG_HANDLE_CHUNK_NEVER, NULL, -1);` (if golfing, use 0 instead of the named constant)

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson From the docs, `all known chunks except for the IHDR, PLTE, tRNS, IDAT, and IEND chunks are affected.` - in other words it won't work because it'll still attempt to validate `tRNS` ;)

Comment: Right, you'd need another call to png_set_keep_unknown_chunks() to eliminate tRNS chunk validation.  tRNS is checked because we consider tRNS to be critical, even though it's officially ancillary.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Well, looks like you just beat the challenge. Just need a language with built-in libpng which lets you set libpng flags.

Comment: @SoniEx2 Almost.  Ubuntu comes with libpng but unfortunately without the "devel" version that's needed to support new code.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Since when is Ubuntu a programming language? Since when is libpng part of the C or C++ standard?

Comment: @SoniEx2: I want to correct myself: there is a "standard Haskell" in regards to libraries which are described in the [Haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/). Ok problem solved for Haskell, sorry for the confusion. Still I think it's better to forbid specific libraries (here: "PNG libraries") than referring to vague terms such as "external library".

Answer (score 4):

## Java - 1220 chars

```java
import java.io.*;import java.util.zip.*;interface Q{static int i(byte[]b,int i){return java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(b).getInt(i);}static boolean v(int x,int...a){return java.util.stream.IntStream.of(a).anyMatch(y->x==y);}static void main(String[]a){byte[]b={-119,80,78,71,13,10,26,10},c={0,0,0,0},d=b.clone();OutputStream I=new InflaterOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());int l,k,i,t,r=k=i=l=0,H=1229472850,D=1229209940,P=1347179589,E=1229278788,L=8192;DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);boolean v;CRC32 C=new CRC32();try{for(v=(in.read(b)>7&&java.util.Arrays.equals(b,d));v=v&&(l=in.readInt())>=0&&in.read(c)>3;){C.update(c);for(byte B:c)v&=(B|32)<123&&(B|32)>96;for(r=0;v&&(t=in.read(b=new byte[l-r>L?L:l-r]))>0;r+=t){C.update(b);if(i(c,0)==D)if(v=v(i,2,3))I.write(b);if(i(c,0)==H&&r==0)if(v=i==0&&t==13){v=i(b,0)>0&&i(b,4)>0&&b[10]==0&&b[11]==0&&v(b[12],0,1)&&((k=b[9])==0&&v(b[8],1,2,4,8,16))||(v(k,2,4,6)&&v(b[8],8,16))||(k==3&&v(b[8],1,2,4,8));i=(v&&k==3)?1:v?k&2:3;}}v&=(k=in.readInt())==(int)C.getValue();C.reset();if(v&(t=i(c,0))==P){v=v(i,1,2)&&l<=768&&l%3==0;i=3;}if(v&t==E){v=l==0;break;}if((t&L)!=0||((t&L<<16)==0&&!v(t,P,H,E,D)))v=0>1;}}catch(IOException e){v=0>1;}System.out.println(v);}}
```

Input is from stdin.

Comment: What happened to "*External library source code size counts towards program size*"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor The stdlib isn't an external library.

Comment: I can't tell if I'm impressed you golfed Java or scared. :P

Comment: @Downgoat Java has built-in CRC32, inflate/deflate, etc. It was only logical. I hope I never have to debug this thing again...

Comment: In that case, why not just use `ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("PNG")`?

Comment: @Downgoat, if one answer with golfed Java scares you, [the almost 2000 on this site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcode-golf%5D+java+is%3Aa+-%5Btips%5D) should terrify you.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The challenge states `Your program must not validate the contents of ancillary chunks, except for their CRC checksums.` I'm sure there's a language out there with a built-in PNG parser that only validates the critical chunks, but I'm pretty sure Java is not one of them.

Comment: Do you have a test case to cover that?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Not yet. Hmm... ugh I forgot to print "false" on unknown critical chunks... .-.

Comment: instead of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you could do `1L<<32-1`

Comment: I could probably optimize this by instead of validating everything myself, I just copied the relevant chunks (IHDR, IDAT, etc) to a new datastream and handed it off to the built-in PNG parser (yes, that's allowed). But eh w/e.

Comment: can't you use `enum` to shorten your code?

Comment: @MilkyWay90 enum?

Comment: @SoniEx2 See the Tips for Golfing in Java question

Comment: @MilkyWay90 haha I have no idea how to modify this code anymore :) but anyway you're welcome to try. it's mostly here as an example for ppl to go off on.

Comment: @SoniEx2 Well, I don't know Java

Comment: @MilkyWay90 you could try golfing it in something else :)